# Using TLS Certificates in IoT Devices

Tags: encryption, tls, iot, arduino

I am not sure whether this is the exact forum to ask this question. If not please transfer it to another.

**Domain**

As we know the IoT is growing rapidly and millions of devices are invading our homes to our cars everyday. Most of these devices do interface with Web APIs. I know we can do this easily in hardware platform such as RaspberryPi or OrangePi.

**Problem**

But when it comes to Hardware with low memory, low storage and without any OS such as Arduino, how can we ensure the transport level security with any Web interface? I am doing a project now with NodeMCU and Arduino Ethernet and I need to ensure my communication with Web APIs are secured.

**Question**

How can I achieve this ? can we use TLS certificates or are there any other methodology ?

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/4/how-to-get-https-on-arduino should help you